# ggvis use of " := " in combination with data.table

Tags: r, data.table, ggvis

When starting up ggvis I get the message :

```
The following object is masked from ‘package:data.table’:

:=
```

That := is essential for running data.table, which happens to be the alternative for dplyr.

My code still runs correctly, but the startup message worries me, since I use data.table in all my scripts.

What are the consequences of using := in both data.table and ggvis, given the startup message of ggvis?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Both `ggvis` and `data.table` have that function defined to prevent that operator from being used outside of the correct syntax (within correct syntax the packages don't let `R` handle the parsing and that function doesn't get called). You can check what exactly each one does by typing `ggvis::":="` and `data.table::":="` (they both just call `stop` unconditionally).

So the only consequence is going to be a somewhat weird error message if you screw up the syntax (e.g. getting the `data.table` error message in `ggvis` or vice versa, depending on which package you load first).